# XQuery to fetch and insert same time

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex, xquery-update

I am retrieving data and inserting it into another file. But the inserted data is not ordered. Following is the example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
let $n := <N>
<n>Lemon</n>
<n>Chickoo</n>
<n>Banana</n>
<n>Orange</n>
<n>Pineapple</n>
<n>Apple</n>
<n>Lemon</n>
<n>Chickoo</n>
<n>Banana</n>
</N>

for $x in distinct-values($n/n)
order by $x 
return 
    insert node  <n>{$x}</n> into doc('fruits')/fruit
```

The output of the `fruits` is as follows -

```
    <fruit>
            <n>Lemon</n>
            <n>Chickoo</n>
            <n>Banana</n>
            <n>Orange</n>
            <n>Pineapple</n>
            <n>Apple</n>
    </fruit>
```

Its not ordered, though mentioned while retrieving... !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in how BaseX evaluates the `order by` FLWOR clause, which is now documented on the [GitHub bug tracker](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/621). The `return` clause is evaluated before sorting instead of afterwords, thus adding the updates in the wrong order.

A workaround would be to either do the sorting in another FLWOR expression:

```
for $x in
  for $d in distinct-values($n/n)
  order by $d
  return $d
order by $x 
return 
    insert node <n>{$x}</n> into doc('fruits')/fruit
```

Another (probably more elegant) solution is to use `insert nodes`, which only has to be evaluated once:

```
insert nodes
  for $x in distinct-values($n/n)
  order by $x 
  return <n>{$x}</n>
into doc('fruits')/fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a bug to me. The spec says:

If multiple nodes are inserted by a single insert expression, their order preserves the node ordering of the source expression.

which isn't exactly crystal-clear, but I think it means you have a right to expect the result to be properly sorted.

What implementation of XQuery Update are you using?

Comment: This is a bug in BaseX, I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/621) on GitHub.